# what is the an implicit conversion must be more specific

Tags: scala

**I want write the Scala value(Array[String]) to the java.util.map,but the error as follows**

**code**

```
val tagsMap = new java.util.HashMap[String, String]()
val fieldsMap = new java.util.HashMap[String, Object]()
// val fieldsMap = new mutable.HashMap[String,Object]()

for (i <- value.indices) {
  fieldstuple(i)._2 match {
    case "int" => fieldsMap.put(fieldsArr(i), Integer.valueOf(value(i)))
    case "varchar" => fieldsMap.put(fieldsArr(i), value(i))
    case "float" => fieldsMap.put(fieldsArr(i),lang.Float.parseFloat(value(i)) )
    case "double" => fieldsMap.put(fieldsArr(i), lang.Double.parseDouble(value(i)))
    case "boolean" => fieldsMap.put(fieldsArr(i), lang.Boolean.parseBoolean(value(i)))
    case "datetime" => fieldsMap.put(fieldsArr(i), value(i))
    case _ => fieldsMap.put(fieldsArr(i), value(i))
  }
}
```

I can't find the reason for this error

**The Error**

```
Error:(151, 81) the result type of an implicit conversion must be more specific than AnyRef
                case "float" => fieldsMap.put(fieldsArr(i),lang.Float.parseFloat(value(i)) )
Error:(152, 85) the result type of an implicit conversion must be more specific than AnyRef
                case "double" => fieldsMap.put(fieldsArr(i), lang.Double.parseDouble(value(i)))
Error:(153, 88) the result type of an implicit conversion must be more specific than AnyRef
                case "boolean" => fieldsMap.put(fieldsArr(i), lang.Boolean.parseBoolean(value(i)))
Error:(151, 81) type mismatch;
 found   : Float
 required: Object
                case "float" => fieldsMap.put(fieldsArr(i),lang.Float.parseFloat(value(i)) )
Error:(152, 85) type mismatch;
 found   : Double
 required: Object
                case "double" => fieldsMap.put(fieldsArr(i), lang.Double.parseDouble(value(i)))
Error:(153, 88) type mismatch;
 found   : Boolean
 required: Object
                case "boolean" => fieldsMap.put(fieldsArr(i), lang.Boolean.parseBoolean(value(i)))
```

Comment: Do you need to use Java types in this code? Manipulating Java types in Scala is always going to be tricky. Where possible, use Scala data types and convert to Java when calling Java code.

Answer (score 0):

It just tells you that you can not put numeric type values to HashMap with Object type of values, because Float Double and etc are not Objects

You should change your HashMap initialization to

```
val fieldsMap = new java.util.HashMap[String, Any]()
```

Comment: your answer is ok,  but the follow java method need accept a  util.HashMap[String, Object] as parameter